# Include inner join subquery in results?

Tags: mysql, sql

I came here yesterday and y'all rocked it. I'm putting together a query that's beyond me right now and have had no luck finding an answer on the Googles. I'm trying to grab the results from a query within the main query and display those as well. Here's the code:

```
SELECT u.id, u.level, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.email
FROM users u
INNER JOIN user_companies uc ON u.id = uc.user_id
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT s.user_id, s.start, s.stop, s.break, s.task
FROM schedule s
WHERE s.start>? AND s.stop<? AND s.multi_id=?)
as s ON (u.id = s.user_id)
WHERE uc.comp_id=? AND uc.status=1 AND
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM schedule_remove sc 
WHERE sc.user_id=u.id AND sc.sched_id=?)
```

Crazy query, simple question. How do I get `s.start, s.stop, s...` into my results query? Right now all I can pull is u.level, u.first_name, etc.

Thanks!

**Update**

I'm an idiot. Thanks websch01lar for the push to realize that. Adding s.stop, etc to the main list worked like it should. I just wasn't checking if $r['stop'] was empty before trying to display the results.

Comment: just include them in the list... u,email, s.stop...

Comment: I've tried that and it returns NULL for the results. For some reason it's not including the second queries results.

Comment: it is a left join, so some records would be null.

Comment: Wish I could like your comment or something. Turns out that particular query I was looking at returned zero results... ran it on a different grouping and it works. Thanks!

Comment: You are able to like a comment.  Just mouseover the comment if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Just include those `s.*` columns in your main/outer query and do a inner join with that table too like below

```
SELECT u.id, u.level, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.email,
s.user_id, s.start, s.stop, s.break, s.task  <-- Here
FROM users u
INNER JOIN user_companies uc ON u.id = uc.user_id
INNER JOIN schedule s ON u.id = s.user_id 
AND (s.start>? AND s.stop<? AND s.multi_id=?)
WHERE 
uc.comp_id=? AND uc.status=1 AND
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM schedule_remove sc 
WHERE sc.user_id=u.id AND sc.sched_id=?)
```